# Processing XML in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I'm looking how to grab all sub elements in a XML file, but something is going wrong.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('C:\\Users\\f6792150\\Documents\profile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Here is what I got:

```
INFO {}
INFO {}
INFO {}
INFO {}
INFO {}
INFO {}
```

I was expecting to get all childs inside the INFO tag, e.g. (TICKER, NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, etc) but it comes empty. Below is the XML file i'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<collection shelf = 'profile'>
<INFO>
    <TICKER>AAPL</TICKER>
    <NAME> Apple Inc.</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>1 Infinite Loop;Cupertino, CA 95014;United State</ADDRESS>
    <PHONE>408-996-1010</PHONE>
    <WEBSITE>http://www.apple.com</WEBSITE>
    <SECTOR>Technology</SECTOR>
    <INDUSTRY>Consumer Electronics</INDUSTRY>
    <FULL_TIME>100,000</FULL_TIME>
    <BUS_SUMM>Apple</BUS_SUMM>
    <SOURCE>https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL</SOURCE> 
</INFO>
<INFO>
    <TICKER>T</TICKER>
    <NAME> AT and T Inc.</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>208 South Akard Street;Dallas, TX 75202;United States</ADDRESS>
    <PHONE>210-821-4105</PHONE>
    <WEBSITE>http://www.att.com</WEBSITE>
    <SECTOR>Communication Services</SECTOR>
    <INDUSTRY> Telecom Services</INDUSTRY>
    <FULL_TIME>254,000</FULL_TIME>
    <BUS_SUMM>at and t</BUS_SUMM>
    <SOURCE>https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/T/profile?p=T</SOURCE>
</INFO>

</collection>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for child in root.findall('./INFO//'):
    print(child.tag,child.text)
```

Output:

```
TICKER AAPL
NAME  Apple Inc.
ADDRESS 1 Infinite Loop;Cupertino, CA 95014;United State
PHONE 408-996-1010
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to get only the child.tag for the first INFO to know what elements where inside each INFO tag.